# Why is vscode IntelliSense only working after typing .default.?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I am trying to use VSCode IntelliSense for a function parameter.

It works with the following code. But unfortunately only after typing `.default.`
but I want to use IntelliSense on the `parentObject`.

```
export default class Data {
    /** @param {import('./mainStore')} parentObject */
    constructor(parentObject) {
        parentObject.default.XXX //<--I get correct Intellisense for the XXX after the "default"
    }
}
```

Using `import('./mainStore').default` doesn't work.

```
export default class Data {
    /** @param {import('./mainStore').default} parentObject */
    constructor(parentObject) {
        parentObject.XXX //<--No IntelliSense here"
    }
}
```

edit: that's an shortened version of the `mainStore.js`. The imported classes contain some functions. I think it's not really nice style but i want to structure my functions and data.

```
import UserStore from "./userStore";
import DataStore from "./dataStore";

const MainStore = {
  user: new UserStore(),
  data: new DataStore()
  construct() {
    this.data = new DataStore(this);
    this.user = new UserStore(this);
    return this; 
  }
}
export default MainStore;
```

I've added two pictures which hopefully explain what i mean:

[Image - Working IntelliSense, but only after using ".default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyLUp.png)

[Image - Not working IntelliSense with import('./mainStore').default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkEse.png)

I've already tried a named export, but it doesn't work either.

How can I get IntelliSense working for the parentObject?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you are doing? Are you passing an object into the constructor or are you passing `import('./mainStore')`?

Comment: sorry, i just added a shortened version of the `mainStore.js`

Answer (score 1):

please check the next url https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/issues/1262. This solution works for me `const { default: validator } = require('validator');`

[image]